# Decode Json object that has different types

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode, codable

I have a Json data which I use to populate Table Views. 
Json has one two type of object in its main part which are "Main" and n-number tableview object;

Main object has two string type in it ("url" and "bar_name"). Tableview objects has 3 type in it ("name", "id", [tableData]). This is common for all tableview objects (n number). Tabledata object which populate cells has 3 different type because one opens a url, other one opens a new table and last one just do an action.

I want to decode this type of json to structures. Is it possible?

```
    //For All Types
protocol commonCellTypes: Codable{
    var type: Int { get }

}
struct User: Codable{
    let mainPage: MainPage?
    let tables: [table]?
}
struct MainPage: Codable{
    let url: String?
    let bar_name: String?
}
struct table: Codable{
    let name: String?
    let id: String?
    let Cells: [commonCellTypes]

    enum CodeKeys: CodingKey
    {
        case name
        case id
        case tableDatas
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodeKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode (String.self, forKey: .name)
        id = try container.decode (String.self, forKey: .id)
        Cells = try container.decode ([commonCellTypes].self, forKey: .tableDatas)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
    {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodeKeys.self)
        try container.encode (name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode (id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode (Cells, forKey: .tableDatas)
    }
}
//Type 2
struct cellType2: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String?
    let url: URL?
    let type: Int
}
//Type 1
struct cellType1: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String
    let table_id: String
    let type: Int
}
//Type 0
struct cellType0: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String
    let type: Int
    let action: String
}
```

[image]

EDIT: I found a similar post but doesn't work for my situation. I'm getting below error

> Type ' table' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

[Swift JSONDecoder with multiple structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931129/swift-jsondecoder-with-multiple-structures)

EDIT2: I added code for decoding but I'm getting nil for both mainPage and User. What am I missing with my structure?

```
  let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let admin = try! decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
            print(admin)
```

Comment: `User` contains a dictionary and `Table1` contains also a dictionary, only `Cells` contains an array. Please **read** the output carefully. JSON got only **two** collection types. It's very simple to distinguish them. **`[]`** is array **`{}`** is dictionary

Comment: @vadian I edit my question. Can you please check it? thank you so much.

Comment: Once again **READ the JSON**. You have to learn to understand the structure. There is no key `tables` and the value is **not** an array. And case sensitivity matters!. `User` got `MainPage`, `Table1` and `Table2` keys

Comment: I understand now. I'm working on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement custom initializer for Decoding and `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` for Encoding. Try this one:

```
//For All Types
protocol commonCellTypes: Codable{

}
struct MainStruct: Codable{
    let tables: [table]
}
struct table: Codable{
    let name: String?
    let id: String?
    let tableDatas: [commonCellTypes]

    enum CodeKeys: CodingKey
    {
    case name
    case id
    case tableDatas
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodeKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode (String.self, forKey: .name)
        id = try container.decode (String.self, forKey: .id)
        tableDatas = try container.decode ([commonCellTypes].self, forKey: .tableDatas)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
    {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodeKeys.self)
        try container.encode (name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode (id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode (tableDatas, forKey: .tableDatas)
    }
}
//Type 2
struct cellType2: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String?
    let url: URL?
    let type: Int
}
//Type 1
struct cellType1: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String
    let table_id: String
    let type: Int
}
//Type 0
struct cellType0: commonCellTypes{
    let cellText: String
    let imageName: String
    let type: Int
    let action: String
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create struct for Admin? which is highest level of json?

Comment: Btw, I have a called tables which is an array of table but in json it is called table-1, table-2 how can I change it for decoding?

Comment: @EmreO. yes if you want to maintain all the tree of JSON response

Comment: I edit my question. Can you please check it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EmreO. you also need to specify your key name for each model variable that is named differently. I would strongly recommend you to read this guide: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/